# SQL server alternative of OR in where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.ID FROM tbl_Case c INNER JOIN
tbl_RequestBaseRequest b ON CaseId = c.ID
WHERE AreCalculationsCompleted = 0
AND b.IsApplicantRequest = 1
and c.IsArchived=0
AND (b.ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ClientRequestId FROM tbl_Response)
OR b.OldClientRequestId IN (SELECT DISTINCT ClientRequestId FROM tbl_Response))
```

> What should be the alternative of OR, this OR is making this query
>   really slow.

Comment: You are running the same subquery twice.  That being the case, you can use the keyword `with` so that you only have to run it once.  This may or may not be a better approach than the ones in the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try removing the `distinct` and being sure you have an index on `tbl_Response(ClientRequestId)`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.ID
FROM tbl_Case c INNER JOIN
     tbl_RequestBaseRequest b
     ON CaseId = c.ID
WHERE AreCalculationsCompleted = 0 AND
      b.IsApplicantRequest = 1 and
      c.IsArchived = 0 AND
      (b.ID IN (SELECT ClientRequestId FROM tbl_Response) OR
       b.OldClientRequestId IN (SELECT ClientRequestId FROM tbl_Response)
      );
```

Other indexes might help.  Also, removing the outer `DISTINCT` (if it is not necessary will also boost performance).  Other indexes might help, but it is not possible to specify because you haven't qualified `AreCalculationsCompleted`.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.ID FROM tbl_Case c 
INNER JOIN tbl_RequestBaseRequest b ON CaseId = c.ID
WHERE AreCalculationsCompleted = 0
AND b.IsApplicantRequest = 1
and c.IsArchived=0
AND exists (SELECT 1 FROM tbl_Response t
  WHERE t.ClientRequestId = b.ID OR t.ClientRequestId = b.OldClientRequestId
)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id
FROM tbl_Case c
JOIN tbl_RequestBaseRequest b ON CaseId = c.id
WHERE AreCalculationsCompleted = 0
    AND b.IsApplicantRequest = 1
    AND c.IsArchived = 0
    AND EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM tbl_Response r
        WHERE r.ClientRequestId IN (b.id, b.OldClientRequestId)
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.ID 
FROM tbl_Case c 
INNER JOIN tbl_RequestBaseRequest b ON CaseId = c.ID
INNER JOIN tbl_Response r ON (b.ID = r.ClientRequestId OR b.OldClientRequestId = r.ClientRequestId)
```

Answer (score 2):

Often rewriting `OR` as `UNION` helps.

```
SELECT c.ID
FROM   tbl_Case c
       INNER JOIN tbl_RequestBaseRequest b
               ON CaseId = c.ID
WHERE  AreCalculationsCompleted = 0
       AND b.IsApplicantRequest = 1
       AND c.IsArchived = 0
       AND b.ID IN (SELECT ClientRequestId
                    FROM   tbl_Response)
UNION
SELECT c.ID
FROM   tbl_Case c
       INNER JOIN tbl_RequestBaseRequest b
               ON CaseId = c.ID
WHERE  AreCalculationsCompleted = 0
       AND b.IsApplicantRequest = 1
       AND c.IsArchived = 0
       AND b.OldClientRequestId IN (SELECT ClientRequestId
                                    FROM   tbl_Response)
```

You could tidy this up somewhat by encapsulating the join of c and b into a CTE and referencing that in both branches of the UNION instead of repeating it - or materialising into a temp table if that initial join is itself expensive.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.ID 
FROM tbl_Case c 
    INNER JOIN tbl_RequestBaseRequest b 
        ON CaseId = c.ID
        AND AreCalculationsCompleted = 0
        AND b.IsApplicantRequest = 1
        AND c.IsArchived=0
        AND EXISTS (SELECT NULL 
                    FROM tbl_Response 
                    WHERE ClientRequestId IN (b.ID, b.OldClientRequestId))
```